# Why is jekyll-spaceship's table processor adding so many break tags/&nbsp;?

Tags: html-table, markdown, jekyll, jekyll-extensions, kramdown

I'm working on a Jekyll website and am using the [jekyll-spaceship](https://github.com/jeffreytse/jekyll-spaceship#1-table-usage) plugin specifically for it's table processor.

**Issue:** I have a 3 column table with 2 rows. The last cell in the row is a multi-line cell, while the first 2 only have 1 line. When the table renders, it places the same number of `<br>` tags under the content in the single line cells, making vertical alignment impossible.

### What I've tried

1. Using `\` at the end, to designate multiple lines

   ```
   | Type | Thumbnail{: width="200" }         | File Types & Sizes                        |
   | :--- | :-------------------------------- | :---------------------------------------- |
   | PNG  | ![PNG][png-image]                 | - [High Res](/img/logos/VTKm_Logo_Hi.png) \
   |      |                                   | - [1024](/img/logos/VTKm_Logo_1024.png)   \
   |      |                                   | - [512](/img/logos/VTKm_Logo_512.png)     \
   |      |                                   | - [256](/img/logos/VTKm_Logo_256.png)     \
   |      |                                   | - [128](/img/logos/VTKm_Logo_128.png)     \
   |      |                                   | - [64](/img/logos/VTKm_Logo_Hi.png)
   | :--- | :-------------------------------- | :---------------------------------------- |
   | SVG  | ![SVG][svg-image]                 | - [SVG](/img/VTKm_Logo.svg)               \
   |      |                                   | - [PDF](/img/logos/VTKm_Logo.pdf)         

   [png-image]: /img/logos/VTKm_Logo_512.png "VTK-m Logo (PNG Version)"
   [svg-image]: /img/VTKm_Logo.svg "VTK-m Logo (SVG Version)"
   ```
2. Making the multiline cell multiple cells, while merging the single line cells upward.

   ```
   | Type | Thumbnail{: width="200" }         | File Types & Sizes                      |
   | :--- | :-------------------------------- | :-------------------------------------- |
   | PNG  | ![PNG][png-image]                 | [High Res](/img/logos/VTKm_Logo_Hi.png) |
   | ^^   | ^^                                | [1024](/img/logos/VTKm_Logo_1024.png)   |
   | ^^   | ^^                                | [512](/img/logos/VTKm_Logo_512.png)     |
   | ^^   | ^^                                | [256](/img/logos/VTKm_Logo_256.png)     |
   | ^^   | ^^                                | [128](/img/logos/VTKm_Logo_128.png)     |
   | ^^   | ^^                                | [64](/img/logos/VTKm_Logo_Hi.png)       |
   | :--- | :-------------------------------- | :-------------------------------------- |
   | SVG  | ![SVG][svg-image]                 | [SVG](/img/VTKm_Logo.svg)               |
   | ^^   | ^^                                | [PDF](/img/logos/VTKm_Logo.pdf)         |

   [png-image]: /img/logos/VTKm_Logo_512.png "VTK-m Logo (PNG Version)"
   [svg-image]: /img/VTKm_Logo.svg "VTK-m Logo (SVG Version)"
   ```

### The results are as follows

Notice all the break tags and `&nbsp;`'s in each attempt.

**Attempt 1:**

```
<tr>
  <td style="text-align: left">
    PNG
    <br>
    &nbsp;
    <br>
    &nbsp;
    <br>
    &nbsp;
    <br>
    &nbsp;
    <br>
    &nbsp;
  </td>
  <td style="text-align: left">
    <img src="/img/logos/VTKm_Logo_512.png" alt="" title="VTK-m Logo (PNG Version)">
    <br>
    &nbsp;
    <br>
    &nbsp;
    <br>
    &nbsp;
    <br>
    &nbsp;
    <br>
    &nbsp;
  </td>
  <td style="text-align: left">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="/img/logos/VTKm_Logo_Hi.png">High Res</a>
        <br>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/img/logos/VTKm_Logo_1024.png">1024</a>
        <br>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/img/logos/VTKm_Logo_512.png">512</a>
        <br>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/img/logos/VTKm_Logo_256.png">256</a>
        <br>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/img/logos/VTKm_Logo_128.png">128</a>
        <br>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/img/logos/VTKm_Logo_Hi.png">64</a>
        <br>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </td>
</tr>
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: left" rowspan="6">
      PNG
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: left" rowspan="6">
      <img src="/img/logos/VTKm_Logo_512.png" alt="" title="VTK-m Logo (PNG Version)">
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: left"><a href="/img/logos/VTKm_Logo_Hi.png">High Res</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: left"><a href="/img/logos/VTKm_Logo_1024.png">1024</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: left"><a href="/img/logos/VTKm_Logo_512.png">512</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: left"><a href="/img/logos/VTKm_Logo_256.png">256</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: left"><a href="/img/logos/VTKm_Logo_128.png">128</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: left"><a href="/img/logos/VTKm_Logo_Hi.png">64</a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

### The results I'm looking for

This is what I'm trying to get as my rendered result.

```
<tr>
  <td style="text-align: left">
    PNG
  </td>
  <td style="text-align: left">
    <img src="/img/logos/VTKm_Logo_512.png" alt="" title="VTK-m Logo (PNG Version)">
  </td>
  <td style="text-align: left">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="/img/logos/VTKm_Logo_Hi.png">High Res</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/img/logos/VTKm_Logo_1024.png">1024</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/img/logos/VTKm_Logo_512.png">512</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/img/logos/VTKm_Logo_256.png">256</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/img/logos/VTKm_Logo_128.png">128</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/img/logos/VTKm_Logo_Hi.png">64</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </td>
</tr>
```

### Conclusion

If anyone can help me figure what I'm doing wrong, or how to achieve my desired solution, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmm, this is the first Markdown table syntax which supports multiline cells that I've seen. Weird syntax (`^^`). I think Pandoc got it right by using a completely different syntax for multiline cells. Although Pandoc still doesn't allow combining columns.

Comment: Afaik Jekyll no longer supports Pandoc though =/

Comment: My thinking is that you are using a weird one-off extension which is probably buggy. It appears to be relatively new, which means it probably hasn't been well tested and many edge cases will break it. And as it is alone in its behavior, there is no other implementations to reference to determine how it should behave in those cases. Personally, I would avoid using it and build my tables using regular old raw HTML. But that's just me.

Comment: If, on the other hand, the developers had instead copied Pandora's already working solution for multiline tables, I would be more comfortable using the extension as there is a known expected behavior.

Comment: @Waylan This is true. The only reason I strayed from raw html tables is because I'm using Tailwind. PurgeCSS in my build process does not look through markdown files and I'm a little lazy when it comes to changing it. I could always just add the styles in the CSS, but that defeats the purpose of using tailwind. That said, if I'm already jumping through hoops just to use tailwind, then there's already a problem I guess.